# Excel macro to count column values of particular column from multiple Excel files in one folder

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

```
Public Sub Sum_Demo()
    Dim myRange
    Dim Results
    Dim Run As Long

    For Run = 1 To 3
        Select Case Run
        Case 1
            myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", "A100")
        Case 2
            myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", "A300")
        Case 3
            myRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", "A25")
        End Select
        Results = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myRange)
        Range("B" & Run) = Results
    Next Run
End Sub
```

please suggest an Excel macro to find count of PID column value from different Excel files in one folder. Column names are same in every file. Number of values in column PID varies. I need output (Separate excel file) as 
Eg:

```
Customer count
ABC       30
PBC       50
```

Comment: Is your data always separated for 1 customer per workbook?

Comment: Two things come to mind: **1)** if you have 1 customer per workbook, you can find PID column ("k") then counta(columns(k))-1 (-1 is for the header) for each workbook, copying the customer name, or **2)** where multiple customers occur in a single workbook you would want to find unique customers and place them in the final workbook, then application.countifs() the PID column for a final value.

Comment: customer varies in each workbook

Comment: any ans?.......

Comment: What does the code you posted have to do with your question?  How is the folder specified?  Have you tried using Dir() to loop over the files in the folder (as used many times in other questions here, so try a search for that)?

Comment: didnt know about Dir() as am new to Excel VBA,I dont know many things.